# Edge length unit cells ionic crystals

Tags: crystal-structure

In ionic crystals there are mainly 3 types of structures: Face-centered cubic and octahedral interstices; face-centered cubic with tetrahedral interstices; and body-centered cubic.

My question is how can I know the edge of the unit cell of this crystals for calculating the theoretical density of a crystal?

Comment: Well, you need to know what type of unit cell the lattice is and the ionic radius of the atom.

Comment: As you see in my question they are all cubic. I know I need to know the ionic radius I'm looking for a formula. For example I know that for Central Cubic Faces $a= 2 (r_{cat} + r_{an})$

Comment: What is the Spanish word you are thinking of? 'corpse' is not the right translation I think.

Comment: @bon - "cubic with central corpse" = "body-centered cubic (bcc)"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography